# Sitecore Invalid Column Name 'Stamp'

Tags: sql-server, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

We have recently upgraded from Sitecore 6.5, rev. 4 to Sitecore 6.6 initial release - and finally to Sitecore 7.0, initial release.

At this point I first began getting the following error (after logging into the content editor and performing a few simple operations): Invalid object name 'EventQueue'.  Upon investigating this, I discovered that our Sitecore databases were outright 'missing' this table, which I then added to each of the databases.  I resumed testing and promptly discovered the missing column 'stamp' error.

My question is, at what point was this field added to the table, and what data type should it be - I'm guessing bigint, but I'd like to be sure?  Also, by chance are there any other known changes to this table and/or the schema, (since it's introduction in 6.3), that I should be aware of, ahead of time?

I really, really don't want to have to back-track and try to re-run the SQL scripts for every upgrade version since Sitecore 6.3.  Just the thought of that makes me sick to my stomach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EventQueue` table has not changed from Sitecore 6.3 rev 110112 (Initial Release) to the latest version of Sitecore. You could drop and re-create the EventQueue table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventQueue](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [InstanceType] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [InstanceData] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [InstanceName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [RaiseLocally] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RaiseGlobally] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Stamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventQueue] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventQueue_Created]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [Created]
GO
```

Note that you could download the latest version of [Sitecore from SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/) as a zip archive and attach the empty databases to compare. Previous versions are also available for download.

But since you may have missed out on a whole bunch of other stuff, I would recommend you compare the database schema from a fresh DB using something like [Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) or [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) from within Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your upgrade wasn't successfull. I would not create these things manually. You would miss out on any indexes etc. that Sitecore might create.

The event queues was introduced in 6.3 and the event queue table should have been added then. The table was created by the following script: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/sitecore6/updates/sitecorecms630.zip

You might just use this, but I would validate that everything in your upgrades have gone right.